# Switch divs when pressing buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons and two divs(I put one above another). I made "info" class visible and "info2" hidden. I need when pressed on "Global" button - "info" div is shown and on the "Asia" button - "info2" div. I tried this code but it's not working:

```
$('.corpo_button_asia').click(function(){ 

                $('.info').hide;
                $('.info2').show;


        }); 

$('.corpo_button_global').click(function(){ 

                $('.info').show;
                $('.info2').hide;


        });
```

Here is html code:

```
<div clas"corpo_buttons">
         <div class="corpo_buttons_global">
                   Global
         </div>
         <div class="corpo_buttons_asia">
                    Asia
         </div>
</div>
<div class="info">
           Info1
</div>
<div class="info2">
           Info2
</div>
```

and css:

```
.corpo_buttons
{
height:50px;
}

.corpo_buttons_global
{
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
width:50px;
float:left;
background-color:rgb(23,55,94);
color:#FFF;
padding:2px;
border:thick;
border-color:rgb(23,55,94);
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
}

.corpo_buttons_asia
{
position:relative;
z-index:2;
left:45px;
width:50px;
float:left;
padding:2px;
background-color:rgb(197,197,197);
padding:2px;
border:thick;
border-color:rgb(23,55,94);
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
}

.info
{
position:absolute;
margin-top:21px;
width:150px;
height:60px;
border:thick;
border-color:#000;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
text-align:left;
padding:5px;
font-size:10px;
}

.info2
{
margin-top:21px;
width:150px;
height:60px;
border:thick;
border-color:#000;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
text-align:left;
padding:5px;
font-size:10px;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: please try to explain the error rather than just saying not working. at lease copy and paste error message you got in the browser console. <div clas should be changed to <div class. (one s is missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be related to your "visibility: hidden;" in .info2. I'd suggest trying it with "display: none;" instead.

The way the jquery show/hide methods work is by toggling the display from none to block and back again. Chances are it's not paying attention at all to your visibility state.

If your absolutely dependant on visibility in your css you can change the code to toggle that one instead:

```
$('.info').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$('.info2').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Answer (score 3):

Notwithstanding the class error noticed by @Sorpigal, the other problem is that you don't actually *call* `.show` and `.hide` because you've omitted the parentheses after the function names.

They should say `.show()` and `.hide()` !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your class assignment reads `<div class="corpo_buttons_asia">` but in jquery you say `.corpo_button_asia` - note the "button" vs "buttons"

Fix this first.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

***[DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/egaqet/edit#javascript,html,live)***

```
$('.corpo_buttons_asia').click(function(){ 
     $('.info').hide();
     $('.info2').show();
}); 

$('.corpo_buttons_global').click(function(){ 
     $('.info').show();
     $('.info2').hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check Corrected one as Below

```
<div>
    <div class="corpo_buttons">
        <div class="corpo_buttons_global">
            Global
        </div>
        <div class="corpo_buttons_asia">
            Asia
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        Info1
    </div>
    <div class="info2">
        Info2
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<script language="javascript">  
$('.corpo_buttons_global').click(function(){  

            $('.info').hide(); 
            $('.info2').show();  

    });
```

$('.corpo_buttons_asia').click(function(){

```
            $('.info').show(); 
            $('.info2').hide(); 


    });  

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

your html class names does not match with jquery selectors.

`‍‍<div clas` in the 1st line of your html should be as `<div class=.` 
 anyway I created a jsfiddle for you. hope this helps
http://jsfiddle.net/5MvHZ/1/